# Flash FLV loader

Tags: jquery, flash, actionscript-3, flv

Afternoon,

Could anyone offer any advice on how to put together a program that will load in external FLV files (with a preloader) on demand as a selection is chosen from a drop down menu.

Wondering whether its best to do this entirely in Flash AS3 or do it via JQuery, either is fine.

For example if I had 3 drop downs with different categories the user would select a category from a drop down and the correct video would be loaded into the player.

Any ideas gratefully received!

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would prefer the flexibility and accessibility of an HTML based solution for as much of the page as possible.  That means that the only compiled Flash element you need on the page is the player itself, and in the future porting to an HTML5 video solution would be much easier.

Communicating video choices to the player from JavaScript is easily done using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html), and communication back from the player to the page would let you automatically select the next video and highlight it in the HTML.

Comment: thanks shane - is it ok to load videos staright from the server or rather than using a streaming service?

Comment: depends on your requirements and hosting arrangements.  For one of my clients I have to use a streaming server because they're concerned about people downloading the videos. Other's get charged heavily by their host for progressive streaming.  It's really something you have to decide on a case by case basis.